# How to retrieve the records based on a date from oracle database

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table with date column in it. I need to fetch the records from it based on 
the given date.

Currently when i used the query:

```
select * from workingemployee_data where created_date like '20-Jan-2012'
```

I am getting those records which have created_date on 20-Jan-2012

But i want to get the records those were created 10 days earlier to a given 
date (i.e) 20-Jan-2012.

Please suggest me on this.

Comment: What is the datatype of this column `created_date`?

Comment: `like` does not make any sense for a DATE

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This gives all records between today and 10 days ago:

```
SELECT *
FROM workingemployee
WHERE created_date BETWEEN sysdate - INTERVAL '10' DAY
                       AND sysdate
```

This gives all records entered exactly 10 days ago:

```
SELECT *
FROM workingemployee
WHERE created_date = sysdate - INTERVAL '10' DAY
```

Replace `sysdate` with exact date if you want.

Comment: Great that it displays records 10 days before system date. But if i try to replace the sysdate with my custom date like created_date ='25-DEC-2011' - INTERVAL '10' DAY                                   it says invalid datatype for date/time interval.

Comment: It seems like your `created_date` is not really of `DATE` type, but `VARCHAR`. This is really bad idea, especially for speed and indexing - please convert this to real `DATE`. But, you can use this expression as workaround: `to_date('25-DEC-2012', 'dd-mon-yyyy')`

Comment: created_date is of type DATE in my table

Comment: ah, ok. still use something like `to_date('25-DEC-2012', 'dd-mon-yyyy')` to convert your input string into real date type

Comment: Glad it helped you! If you have index on `created_date`, it should work very fast

Comment: @mvp, you're right it will work fast but only if the time part of `created_date` is `00:00:00` otherwise it will not match (this is why I used `trunc` in my answer)

Comment: @A.B.Cade: according to OP, `created_date` is of type `DATE`, not `DATETIME` or `TIMESTAMP`. For `DATE`, time part does not exist and this does not matter. Also, if this was the case, filter by equality would not have worked.

Comment: @mvp, in oracle **all** dates contain time... the fact that it works shows that the time is `00:00:00`, but if someone, some day will insert something like sysdate (which is already a date and contain time which isn't `00:00:00`), then strange things might happen...

Comment: @A.B.Cade: ah, I see: [sqlfiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9eecb/30) - thanks! But, if someone always uses `to_date(x, 'yyyy-mm-dd')` to store the date, this should not be a problem.

Comment: @mvp, assuming `x` is varchar2 - yes (you sould never try using to_date on a date - oracle will use implicit conversions to varchar2 which can give unexpected results)

Answer (score 4):

1. Why do you use `like` and not `=` ?
2. Assuming that `created_date` is of type `DATE`, it's bad practice to rely on implicit conversion according to `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` (this is what happens when you compare a date and a string)
3. `dd-mon-yyyy` isn't a good format for querying since it deffers according to `NLS_LANGUAGE` better use `mm` for months numbers

So, either use [@mvp's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14670702/1083652) or do something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM workingemployee
WHERE trunc(created_date) = to_date('20-01-2013', 'dd-mm-yyyy') - 10
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this solution cannot make use of possible index on `created_date`, thus it will be using full table scan - very slow, especially if table is big.

Comment: This can be workedaround by either using `function based indexes` or by using `create_date >= to_date('20-01-2013 000000', 'dd-mm-yyyy hh24miss') - 10 and create_date >= to_date('20-01-2013 235959', 'dd-mm-yyyy hh24miss') - 10`

Answer (score 1):

SELECT *
FROM workingemployee
WHERE created_date > sysdate - INTERVAL '10' DAY;